Transposing and concatenating tensors in PyTorch
I have two tensors in PyTorch:
tensor1 = torch.rand(4, 2)
tensor2 = torch.rand(10, 4)

I want to transpose the first one, to be able to then concatenate it to the second.
tensor1_t = torch.transpose(tensor1, 0, 1)

concat_tensor = torch.cat((tensor1_t, tensor2), dim=0)

assert concat_tensor.shape[0] == tensor1_t.shape[1] + tensor2.shape[0]
assert concat_tensor.shape[1] == tensor1_t.shape[0]


But doing like this gives me unspecified AssertionError. Can someone help me figure this out?

The concatenation works as expected. However, your first assertion necessarily fails, as you add the shape[1] value of the already transposed tensor tensor1_t to the shape[0] value of tensor2. What you need to add is either shape[0] of tensor1_t or shape[1] of tensor1 (which has not been transposed).
If you fix this, then exactly the same problem will happen with your second assertion, so you will also have to fix it there.
Both of the following versions will work as expected:

Compare same dimensions from transposed tensor:
assert concat_tensor.shape[0] == tensor1_t.shape[0] + tensor2.shape[0]
assert concat_tensor.shape[1] == tensor1_t.shape[1]


Compare opposite dimensions from original tensor:
assert concat_tensor.shape[0] == tensor1.shape[1] + tensor2.shape[0]
assert concat_tensor.shape[1] == tensor1.shape[0]



If you want to get more specific AssertionErrors, you can add a string as an error message after the assertion. In your case, you could have written, for example:
message = (f"concat_tensor: {concat_tensor.shape}, "
           f"tensor1_t: {tensor1_t.shape}, tensor2: {tensor2.shape}")
assert concat_tensor.shape[0] == tensor1_t.shape[1] + tensor2.shape[0], message
# >>> AssertionError: concat_tensor: torch.Size([12, 4]), 
#     tensor1_t: torch.Size([2, 4]), tensor2: torch.Size([10, 4])

From the printout, you could have noticed that all tensor shapes match along dimension 1, including tensor1_t (which is already transposed, as mentioned above).
